# Compare 2 text files and output lines unique in only 1 file while ignoring case

Tags: unix, text, diff, comm

I have 2 large text files `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`

Each file contains a line separated list of names e.g.

**file1.txt**

```
Beth
james
James
paul
Paul
sally
```

**file2.txt**

```
James
Paul
Sally
```

I want to produce a file containing names unique ONLY to `file1.txt` while also ignoring case, so in the above example I want a file produced which would look like this:

**comparison.txt**

```
Beth
```

Using the command `comm -23 file1.txt file2.txt > comparison.txt` produces an incorrect result:

```
Beth
james
paul
sally
```

Using the `-i` command also produces an incorrect result:

```
Beth
James
Paul
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Awk` with `POSIX` compatible string-function `tolower` for doing a case insensitive lookup.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{unique[tolower($0)]++; next}!(tolower($0) in unique)' file2.txt file1.txt
Beth
```

re-direct to a file `comparison.txt` as

```
awk 'FNR==NR{unique[tolower($0)]++; next}!(tolower($0) in unique)' file2.txt file1.txt > comparison.txt
cat comparison.txt
Beth
```

The idea behind the logic is

So my understanding of the solution I did as follows,

1. `FNR==NR{unique[tolower($0)]++; next}` will process on `file2.txt`
   storing the entries of the array as a case in-sensitive words till
   the end of `file2.txt`.
2. Now on `file1.txt,` I can match those rows from other file by doing
   `!(tolower($0) in unique)` which will give me all those rows in
   `file1.txt` whose lines are not present in `file2.txt`

(or) if you access to `GNU grep` using the negative match on the files, with `-i` for care insensitive look-up

```
grep -viFxf file2.txt file1.txt
Beth
```

Comment: @bullhorn: Happy to help! Make sure you understand the usage for future references!